# Put a button to the right and middle of a layout

Tags: android

If I have a layout in xml as follow

```
<RelativeLayout
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bFb"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button                       //This is the button on question
        android:id="@+id/bFb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="Button" /> 

//there are more stuffs here below the linear layout
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I have the button to the right of the linearlayout AND aligned at the middle of linear layout? I don't want the button borders to stretch the whole linear layout, just the middle of the linear layout

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: i suggest you to use 9patch images. for the button when you stretch i not effect the buttons borders.

Comment: please provide your correct code. Do not delete things from the original. it creates problem. And by what you have posted, your whole layout itself seems incorrect. No height, width etc property for relativelayout??

Comment: @Emmanuel The answer below provides a picture of what I want.

Comment: @AtishAgrawal  What do you mean? hight and width are all fill parent/wrap content and they show up perfectly. There is not need to put 20 other components below that are irrelevant to the quetion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by changing `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and supply a `weight` for its first child like that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Which will produce this [image]

**EDIT**
You can achieve it with relative layout that way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bFb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it needs some tweeks to produce the exact same thing, in my opinion LinearLayout's weight serve better in your case, so if I were in your shoe I choose the LinearLayout solution and wrap it in a RelativeLayout

Comment: Thank you Ahmad. Is there anyway I can keep the relativelayout at the top while achieving what you are showing? I wil laccept this asnwer since it does answer the question. But if I get another answer with relative layout kept at the root, I will have to change the accepted answer

Comment: ooopsI thought I accepted it already! I just did it agin. Thanks :)